# Passing Information to Drupal Referenced Entities before Render

Tags: 8, theming, entities

I have a content type called `basic_page`.  This content type has a field called `field_elements` which is an entity reference field.  The display settings for this field is set to 'Render Entity' - in other words, when a `basic_page` node is being rendered, it will also render the referenced entity.  All good - no problem.

My question is, I would like to pass run-time information (based on `basic_page` node) to the referenced entity that should be used in `mytheme_preprocess_node` when the referenced entity is being 'pre-processed`.

The problem is, by the time `hook_preprocess_node` is called for the referenced entity - I have no information of the `basic_page` node that 'contains' the referenced entity.

I was hoping that in `hook_preprocess_field` I could check if it is `field_element` and then set some value in the &$variables param I am getting in `hook_preprocess_field` that will persist to exist up to the point where `hook_preprocess_node` is called?

Answer (score 1):

This works as designed. The referenced node can have multiple parents, but is only processed once and then cached.

A slighly different approach would be to use the context to check inside the referenced node, which parent node is displayed as page content.

Load the basic node with a route match in preprocess of the referenced node. See this question from today on blocks, which can be used in the node preprocess hook in the same way:

[How to access field values from a custom block](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204851/how-to-access-field-values-from-a-custom-block)

You would also have to adjust the cache settings of the referenced node, see the comment in the linked answer.